# CI pipeline Coverity on jenkins

Tags: linux, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, coverity

I am building Coverity pipeline in jenkins with linux build machine. I am getting the following error.

Caused: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "cmd" (in directory "D:\DEVOPS_TOOLSET\workspace\COVERITY_CHECK_APP"): error=2, No such file or directory

Comment: I am facing similar issue. Did you find a solution for this issue?

Comment: My app is using Kotlin. Currently coverity does not support Kotlin. This is the issue in my case.